# What is a polite way to ask "may I ask who is speaking?"

Tags: politeness

A man I don't know calls me and starts talking to me in Chinese. All is fine, except I don't know who he is. I sense I'm not the person he's looking for. How do I ask who he is without being too blunt: "你是誰?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several ways to say it:

*Polite*:

**请问，你是哪位?**

**Qǐng wèn** (May I ask), **nǐ shì** (you are) **nǎ** (which) **wèi** (identifier for people/position)

May I ask, who is this?

---

**您好， 您找谁？**

**Nín hǎo** (hello), **nín** (polite form of you) **zhǎo** (looking) **sheí** (who)?

Hello, whom are you looking for?

---

**喂，请问您是谁？**

**Wei** ("hi"- typical way people answer the phone), **qǐng wèn nín shì sheí?**

Hi, who is this please (...**,** 请问 is "please". 请问 **,**... is "excuse me") ?

---

*Impolite*:

**喂？ 哪位？**

**Wèi nǎ wèi**

Hi, who is this...?

---

**找谁呀？**

**Zhǎo sheí ya** ("ya" is a participle equivalent to 啊 "ah" expressing surprise or doubt)?

Who are you lookin' for?

These are the ones I typically hear... although there are more.

Comment: Yo son your English is fading as your Mandarin strengthens... "these are the ones I typically *here*"

Comment: The mixed use of 你 and 您 in the 2nd sentence seems weird. I would pick either and stick with it.

Comment: @NS.X. Good catch- oops. at B.D, lol that's not good :O

Comment: @Growler Word to word, `请问` is more closer to `May I ask ...`, and `对不起/不好意思` = `excuse me`. However, `请问您是谁` = `who is this please` is good translation.

Comment: Another polite way: 敢問閣下尊姓大名 gan3 wen4 ge2 xia4 zun1 xing4 da4 ming2. 敢問 = 請問 ＋ humbler attitude. 閣下 = 您 + humbler attitude. 尊姓大名 = notable family name and great given name.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "请问, 您是哪位" in the first example?

Comment: @NS.X. I'd go with "您好, 请问找谁?" for the second example

Comment: @TGMCians I'm not sure I know what you mean.

Comment: @TGMCians I am taking a look now.

Answer (score 1):

Polite: 请问您是哪位？

Impolite: 哎，你是哪个？

Alternatively, you could politely ask him who he is looking for:

Polite: 请问您找谁？

Answer (score 1):

Some people (at least in Taiwan) also say (你)哪里找, which to me doesn't seem either super polite or super impolite...really just depends on tone of voice.

Answer (score 0):

Politer than `你是誰?` is `你是哪一位?`.

(Side note: I'd also like to point out that `這是誰?` is wrong, while `你是誰?` is acceptable. You got this right, but it's not obvious to a lot of learners.)

Comment: I think I've heard "這是誰?" before, although it's pretty rude.

Comment: @Growler And in English, it's the opposite. "Who _are_ you?" is very in-your-face and rude, while "Who is this?" is pretty standard.

Comment: Yeah that's actually true, lol. Never thought about that.

Comment: I guess what @Growler heard is in fact `這誰啊`, yeah, quite blunt. In `你是哪一位`, the 一 is usually dropped, so `您哪位` or `您是哪位`.